# How can i remove all unnecessary values in JSON with regex?

Tags: regex

How can i find all unnecessary values in the following JSON example with regex to minimize string json data.

**Unnecessary Value conditions:**

- **key**=any and **value**= 0
- **key**=any and **value**= 0.0
- **key**=any and **value**= "0000-00-00"
- **key**=any and **value**= ""  (empty string)
- **key**=any and **value**= []  (empty array)
- **key**=any and **value**= {}  (empty object)
- **key**=ends with "ID" and **value**= all chars of value are 0 ("000" or "00000" or "0")

**json example:**

```
{ "a_3":0, "a_1":"", "a_4":0.0, "a_2":"0000-00-00", "a_5":[], "a_6":{}, "a_7ID":"0000000000","b_12ID":"0000000001", "a_8ID":"000000","b_1":0.1,"b_2":2, "b_3":1.0, "b_4":"0", "b_5":"sf" }
```

(I named unnecessary keys starting with "a_" above)

**My Work:** https://regex101.com/r/kMe3Zt/4

Regex :`(\"[^"]*\"\s*:(((\[\])|(\"\")|"0000-00-00"|"0000000000"|(\{\}))|(0.0))+,?)`

c# code:

```
  public static string clearJSON(string data)
    {
        var regexx = @"(\""[^""]*\""\s*:((\[\])|\""\""|0|""0000-00-00""|""0000000000""|(\{\}))+,?)";
        var result = "";
        do
        {
            result = Regex.Replace(data, regexx, string.Empty);
        } while (Regex.IsMatch(result, regexx));
        return result.Replace(",}", "}").Replace(",]", "]");
    }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There may be an easier way... if you are using JSON.NET (everyone is the days), you can use a couple of settings to ditch the null and default values:

```
var jsonSerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings 
{ 
      NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore, 
      DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore 
 };
```

More info here: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationSettings.htm

Comment: Yes , this is  best solution i think too . But in my case, there are thousands of fields of web services  (i call many different clients web services and everyday we add new web services) and this fields generated automatically by .net. So it will be really difficult to override all fields to define their default values as below.  I need to define default values for all fields to be able use your solution.  :(   https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_DefaultValueHandling.htm